# Error building tesseract in visual studio 2010 using emcripten

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tesseract, emscripten

I'm having following error when i'm trying to build tesseract VS2010 bundle in visual studio 2010 using emscripten.
I configured visual studio as they have mentioned in their documentation. but when i click build solution i get following error.

```
error MSB4044: The "GCCCompile" task was not given a value
for the required parameter "GCCToolPath"
```

How can i fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with some other project and fixed it by changing the "Platform Toolset" to "Emscripten" in the project "Configuration Properties"

Ideally it should have changed automatically when I switched to Emscripten as the platform, but somehow it didn't.

Additionally set the "Configuration Type" to "Console Application (.js)" (or html as you would require)